# Upgrade to TFS 2018 losing release triggers

Tags: tfs

We are heavy users of vNext Release Management. Testing our upgrade of TFS 2017 Update 3 to 2018 Update 1 the artifact trigger, along with each environment's pre-deployment triggers have all been reset.

I can't find anything in the release notes that warns about this. Is there some setting or process we've missed that will avoid us having to re-configure all the settings?

In the below there should be an artifact set, and then lines between UAT, Pre Prod and Prod.

[image: Release setup]

Comment: How did you upgrade your TFS? Did you do [a dry run in a pre-production environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/pre-production?view=tfs-2017), or [in a production environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/upgrade/walkthrough?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2018)? Please check event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is anything useful.

Comment: Hi @Cece, we tested the upgrade in a pre-production environment. There's nothing relevant in Event Viewer for the upgrade period.

Comment: Not for the upgrade period, is there any error message related to Release now?